# Can I develop a Flutter iOS application on Windows with a simple LAN connection to a Mac?

Tags: ios, flutter, windows, macos, xamarin

I'm a **Xamarin** developer considering a move to **Flutter**.

I have a powerful **Windows** desktop and a mid-range **Mac** laptop.

For my Xamarin development, I was able to develop for iOS on my windows machine, as long as my mac was connected on a network. That allowed me to build an iOS app, and preview it on Windows via an iPhone simulator.

The only thing I needed the Mac for was to be connected and turned on, and for when I wanted to deploy to the App Store.

Is it possible to have a similar setup with Flutter? The reason I don't want to do all my development on my Mac is:

- My Mac is much less powerful than my Windows machine
- I'm much more comfortable with the Windows OS

Both these factors will significantly influence my productivity.

I've done a lot of googling on this topic but can't find one that asks the exact question I'm asking. Most are addressed at trying to avoid a hardware mac completely.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In flutter you can not do that because flutter pods and IOS limitations do not support this. but you can build IOS app on windows using any virtual machine(not recommended ) or Remote Mac Machine(Codemagic or MacStadium) visit these websites for remote access to any mac device for your work)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rana. So I guess that means I'm better off just developing directly on my macbook